# Share records related to a record type using groups

Tags: account, record-type, permission-sets, public-group

I have several recordtype on the account. I created a permission set that has access to a certain recordtype but there is no view all, but I need the user to have access to all the records created with that one recordtype.
I was thinking of making two groups, one that has the permission set and the other that doesn't have that permission. But then I don't know how to do the rest.
Any idea what I'm missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permission Sets can't do this. What you would want to do is to create a Criteria-Based Sharing Rule, which would be configured to say that all records with the specific record record type are shared to a Public Group. The group would contain all the users that need this level of access. The Permission Set itself is not necessary.

Comment: I did a test and it worked, thanks for the help :)